# Split paired fasta files with nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I have a pair of fasta files, that I want to split into smaller chunks to parallelize the processing.

The first fasta `reads.fasta` contains DNA sequences

```
>/kingdoms/rce/workspace1/Nanopore/20180223-run9/RawData/BC-BD-chr10/i0013771_20180416_FAH66366_MN19358_sequencing_run_1042_63976_read_126980_ch_412_strand.fast5_template_deepnano {'mapped_end': 24599, 'num_matches': 22704, 'mapped_strand': '+', 'clipped_bases_end': 18, 'num_insertions': 715, 'mapped_start': 226, 'mapped_chrom': 'chr10', 'num_mismatches': 795, 'clipped_bases_start': 154, 'num_deletions': 874} 
CXXACCCGGAGXXXCAGCXAAAAGCXAXACXXACXACCXXTAXXXTATGXXXACXXXXXAXAGACXGTCXXXXCAXCCXACXCCTXCGCACTTGXCXCXCGCXACXGCCGXGCAACAAACACXAAAXCAAAACAGXAAAAXACXACAXCAAAACGCATAXXCCCXAGAAAAAAAXXXTCXXACAATAXACXAXACXACACAAXACABAAXCAGXGACXXXCGXAACAACAAXXXCCTXCACXCXCCAACTXCXCXGCXCGAAXCCCXACATAAXAATATAXCAAAXCXACCGXCXGGAACAXCAXCGCXAXCCAGCXCXTTGXGAACCGCXACCAXCAGCABGXACAGXGGXACCCXCGTGXCAXCXGCAGCGAGAACTXCAACGXXXGCCAAAXCAAGCCAATGXGGXAACAACCACACC
>/kingdoms/rce/workspace1/Nanopore/20180223-run9/RawData/BC-BD-chr10/i0013771_20180416_FAH66366_MN19358_sequencing_run_1042_63976_read_55042_ch_362_strand.fast5_template_deepnano {'mapped_end': 202484, 'num_matches': 12382, 'mapped_strand': '-', 'clipped_bases_end': 33, 'num_insertions': 442, 'mapped_start': 189194, 'mapped_chrom': 'chr10', 'num_mismatches': 461, 'clipped_bases_start': 20, 'num_deletions': 447} 
XGAXXXTAATGXTAAAXCGAXAGXACCAAGXCXXTTGTTGTAXACXAGAXCCAXXCCXAATATAXCTGTAXCGAGXACAXCGXCTAXXAATGXXCCTGXAAXXXXCAGXXCAAAAXXACXXXXCAAXTBGXXTAXGAAXXCAXCCAAXCXCTGXXCAXXGCXXGCCGCAAXXACGCAGXCAXCAACAXAGACXGCAAXCAXXAGAXXXXBAXCCXCGGXXXGGTAXAAXCCCGGAGTAXAAGAGXXATCXXXCAGXCCAAXXCCAXXCAAGTATTGTCXXAGAXGAXCAXXCCAXTCXXXAGGACXCTGXXXXAGACCATAXAACGCCXTAXXXAGCXXGACXACACAXCXCCXAXCAXGCGGATGXGGGATGTATAXXBCTTCTXCCAAXXXAGCATAXAGGAAXGCAXGAXXGA
...
```

The second fasta `reads.fasta_values` contains a sequence of values separated by a space, that correspond to the DNA sequence of the `reads.fasta` (in the same order)

```
>/kingdoms/rce/workspace1/Nanopore/20180223-run9/RawData/BC-BD-chr10/i0013771_20180416_FAH66366_MN19358_sequencing_run_1042_63976_read_126980_ch_412_strand.fast5_template_deepnano
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03
>/kingdoms/rce/workspace1/Nanopore/20180223-run9/RawData/BC-BD-chr10/i0013771_20180416_FAH66366_MN19358_sequencing_run_1042_63976_read_55042_ch_362_strand.fast5_template_deepnano
0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09
...
```

I want to get several pairs of smaller files.

Currently, I have tried to pair them, then split them, but that only splits the first file of the pair.

```java
Channel
    .fromFilePairs("reads{.fasta,.fasta_values}", flat:true)
    .splitFasta(by: 1, file:true)
    .println()
```

Output:

```
[reads, reads.1.fasta, reads.fasta_values]
[reads, reads.2.fasta, reads.fasta_values]
[reads, reads.3.fasta, reads.fasta_values]
```

While I want something like this

```
[reads, reads.1.fasta, reads.1.fasta_values]
[reads, reads.2.fasta, reads.2.fasta_values]
[reads, reads.3.fasta, reads.3.fasta_values]
```

I think something similar is doable with `fastq` files for paired-end reads, but I could not find out how to do it with `fasta` files.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it, just needed the argument `elem` in `splitFasta`

```java
Channel
    .fromFilePairs("reads{.fasta,.fasta_values}", flat:true)
    .splitFasta(by: 1, file:true, elem:[1,2])
    .println()
```